# What is the command to list contents of directory with Google chrome cloud shell SSH browser console?

Tags: shell, google-cloud-platform, ssh

I tried `ls` command (and multiple others), but it's not working, how do I list the files in the directory and navigate around?

I'm attaching file to explain what I mean:

[image]

Comment: What is your question/problem? The **ls** command is working in CloudShell. Are you trying to list the directories of something else like a VM? If yes, then you need to **ssh** into that VM instance. There are many tutorials on how to connect to instances in Google Cloud.

Comment: The ls command is not working as shown in image on top, trying to list files in the directory, and if that works, navigate with CD like in normal linux, but none of the commands seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried in my cloud shell and am able to list my files and navigate to the directories present. The ls command is used to list files or directories in Linux and unix. You can try using ls-a which will list the files and directories including hidden files that begin with a “.”.

[image]

If you want to display files and directories that are in the VM then you need to SSH to the respective VM instance and then try using ls -a  command then it will display the respective files and directories along with hidden files. There may be a possibility that there are no directories within your cloud shell. Please refer to the images attached.
[image]

Comment: Ok, got it, I navigated from wrong section in Google cloud! Thanks a million ;)